# Sentinel Feat vs. Creatures with Flyby

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

From the *Players Handbook*, the Sentinel feat grants the following abilities:

> When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature's speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.
> Creatures provoke opportunity attacks from you even if they take the Disengage action before leaving your reach.
> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn't have this feat), you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

There are a few creatures with the Flyby trait which, taking a peryton as an example, grants the following abilities:

> The peryton doesn't provoke an opportunity attack when it flies out of an enemy's reach.

So my question is what happens when a peryton flies out of reach of a sentinel?  Does the sentinel get to attack or does the creature fly away safely?

Comment: There's no need to delete a question closed as a duplicate; you can leave it up as a signpost for future readers to help them find the question yours was closed as a duplicate of. :)